# Why isn't my water heater heating after element and thermostat replacement?

Tags: water, heater

I have an A.O. Smith 50 gallon water heater I replaced the upper and lower thermostat and element and still not getting hot water I notice that if I close the valve on the hot water it will heat but after 2 minutes of the valve being open it won't heat again until I shut the hot water off again

Answer (score 1):

Is the water running? If the water is running faster then it can heat up it will always be cold. Close the valve so it can heat up.

Comment: Your answer could be deciphered by someone that is familiar with maintenance but it isn't really formatted for a novice to understand. Perhaps you could reword your answer a bit and make it more clear? I'll give you a +1 for effort but please "edit" your answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you fill the tank with water before you turned the power back on to the water heater? If not, the element(s) may have burnt out.
- Did you wait a good while before turning the hot water on? The water heater will take a while to heat a completely cold tank. The upper element will turn on first. Once that temperature is reached, the bottom element will come.
- Are all of the connections tight? Turn off the power to the tank and make sure all of the screws are tight.
- Are the elements getting appropriate voltage? Turn on the power and read the voltage at the upper element. Once you check the voltage you can turn the temperature dial on that element all the way down and the lower element will come on. Check power at that element.
- A new element could be bad.
- You might have a bad breaker.